# Why does while (cin >> a); doesn't let me enter anything for the rest of the loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{

    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   

        cout << "hello\a" << endl;
        while (cin >> a); 
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << "*******************************" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Look at the above cpp code.

After compiling the code and running the a.out, I enter a few integers and a non integer to jump out of **while (cin >> a);** .

I thought I would be given the opportunity to enter things for every loop until i reaches 10.

Here's the output:

```
hello
121 21 3123 f
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
hello
0
*******************************
```

**Why the rest of the loops except the first one does not let me enter anything?**

Answer (score 1):

When you enter something that can't be converted to the desired type (a non-number where you tried to read a number, for example) the stream is place in a "failed" state. In this state, all further attempts at reading will fail.

You can clear the failed state with `yourstream.clear();`

At that point, whatever non-number "stuff" you entered to get it to exit the first loop will still be in the input buffer, so the next attempt at reading will see that as its first input.

Beyond that, right now you're attempting to read all the input until conversion fails (or you reach EOF, etc.) before you do anything else. From the looks of things, you probably want to read, display, and repeat as long as you get numbers. For example, something on this general order:

```
while (std::cin >> a) {
    std::cout << a;
}

// clear the failed state
std::cin.clear();

// and read a string:
std::string b;
std::cin >> b;
std::cout << b;
```

Now if we enter `1 2 3 abc`, the first loop will read and display the `1`, `2` and `3`, then the second `cin >> b` will read the `abc`.